# Can't figure out how to display all elements in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```
var questions = [
    ['Whats 5 + 10? ', 15],
    ['Whats 5 + 15? ', 20],
    ['Whats 5 + 20? ', 25],
]
var questionsCorrect = [];
var questionsIncorrect = [];

var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;
var question; 
var answer;
var response; 
var html;

function print(message) {
    document.write(message);
}

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++ ) {
    question = questions[i][0];
    answer = questions [i][1];
    response = parseInt(prompt(question));
    if (response === answer) {
    correct++;
    questionsCorrect = '<br> Answered correctly: </br>' + '<li>' + question + 

**'</li>';
    }   
    }
html = 'You answered ' + correct + ' question(s) correctly';
print(html);

document.write(questionsCorrect);
```

Beginner here and first time posting to SO so forgive me if I've royally screwed this up. All I'm trying to accomplish here is display the answers the user got correct and incorrect. I do not understand why the array is only returning the last item in that array. I think once I figure this out everything else will fall into place. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: change `questionsCorrect = ` to `questionsCorrect += ` the issue is that you are not concatenating (fancy term for combining or adding to the string) so every time you hit `questionsCorrect = ` you are throwing out the previous value. You are really only storing the last value in the array.

Comment: @AdamH since he's trying to use an array, he should use questionsCorrect.push() to add each new correct answer, then loop through the array to display it. He's basically creating an array, then overwriting it with a string.

Comment: @roccobarbi you are correct, I'll update my answer to point to yours.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It's amazing how obvious it is when someone points it out!

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment here is the 'fixed' code:

```js
var questions = [
  ['Whats 5 + 10? ', 15],
  ['Whats 5 + 15? ', 20],
  ['Whats 5 + 20? ', 25],
]
var questionsCorrect = [];
var questionsIncorrect = [];

var correct = 0;
var incorrect = 0;
var question;
var answer;
var response;
var html;

function print(message) {
  document.write(message);
}

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  question = questions[i][0];
  answer = questions[i][1];
  response = parseInt(prompt(question));
  if (response === answer) {
    correct++;
    questionsCorrect += '<br> Answered correctly: </br>' + '<li>' + question + '</li>';
  }
}
html = 'You answered ' + correct + ' question(s) correctly';
print(html);

document.write(questionsCorrect);
```

please see @roccobarbi answer as it addresses the underlying issue and not just this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Adam H mentions under your post, but you are assigning an empty array [], to questionsCorrect, so I assume you want it to be an array. Just "push" your correct answers into it.

```
questionsCorrect.push('<br> Answered correctly: </br>' + '<li>' + question + '</li>');
```

and to display it, just do:

```
document.write(questionsCorrect.join());
```